# Adding product without page refresh in shopify

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, cart

This is my first post here. I was working on adding list of product in my shopify mini cart. I have successfully added the products to the mini cart but when I click add to cart, it takes me to the cart page. Is there any way that I can add the product with ajax? My shopify theme is Flow which already has ajax. But my I have no clue how to use it in my custom code.

Here is the code that I am trying to work with:

```
<div class="Hotproducts">
  <div class="HP-1">{% assign product = all_products['product-name'] %}

    {% if product == blank %}
      <h5>No product found</h5>
    {% else %}
      <h5>{{ product.title }}</h5>

      <div class="hot-product-images">
        <img src="#">
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
      </div>
      <form id="hpaddtocart" method="post" action="/cart/add">
        <input name="id" value="43494769656049" type="hidden" />
        <input id="hp-text-colr" name="add" value="Add to cart" type="submit" />
      </form>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but what to change deeply depends on your theme.

In general to update the cart you send an ajax request similar to this

```
for (var i = 0; i < variantsId.length; i++) { // let's say you have an array of the variants you want to add to the cart and the matching quantities
    items.push({
        id: variantsId[i],
        quantity: quantities[i],
        properties: properties[i] || {}
    }) // properties is optional
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: {
        items: items
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        //show Loading
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // update the cart. Here you may even want to call the cart.js endpoint
    },
    error: function(e, status, errorThrown) {
        //show error
    }
});
```

Check this page for more js apis: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart